# MySQL Select three results for active, expired and unactive by comparing date

Tags: mysql

I have this table

```
card_id | activated | expiry_date 
---------------------------------------------
1       |    0      | 19-01-2015 19:00
2       |    1      | 20-10-2014 08:00
3       |    1      | 04-12-2014 22:30
4       |    0      | 12-11-2015 10:00
5       |    1      | 01-02-2016 03:30
6       |    0      | 16-08-2015 16:00
7       |    1      | 13-06-2015 12:00
8       |    1      | 03-02-2015 01:30
9       |    0      | 18-02-2016 15:00
10      |    1      | 10-05-2015 12:30
```

I have activated and not-activated cards, then I also have their expiry dates.

I wish to select these results into three categories (unactivated, active and expired) depending on the status of the activated field and compare the expiry date with the present time THEN LIMIT 3 PER CATEGORY.

The expected outcome for this case will be:

#### Unactivated

```
card_id | activated | expiry_date 
---------------------------------------------
1       |    0      | 19-01-2015 19:00
4       |    0      | 12-11-2015 10:00
6       |    0      | 16-08-2015 16:00
```

#### Active

```
card_id | activated | expiry_date 
---------------------------------------------
5       |    1      | 01-02-2016 03:30
7       |    1      | 13-06-2015 12:00
8       |    1      | 03-02-2015 01:30
```

#### Expired

```
card_id | activated | expiry_date 
---------------------------------------------
2       |    1      | 20-10-2014 08:00
3       |    1      | 04-12-2014 22:30
```

How can I do this preferably using just one MySQL query?

Comment: What specifically are you stuck on? You can use `UNION` or `UNION ALL` to return multiple results in one query, provided each result set has same number and type of columns.

Comment: @shree.pat18 How to compare the dates and also how to limit by three...

Comment: Hmm, perhaps you should spend some time on a good tutorial first, because these are fairly standard things. In a nutshell, you will use a `WHERE` clause wherein you will check the value of `activated` and possibly compare the `expiry_date` to the current date, depending on which status you are checking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unactivated:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE activated = 0 LIMIT 3;
```

Note though, that a `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` is meaningless, as there's no order in a relational database, unless you specify it.

Active:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE activated = 1 AND expiry_date > CURDATE() LIMIT 3;
```

Expired:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE activated = 1 AND expiry_date < CURDATE() LIMIT 3;
```

If you don't have to limit each query, I'd recommend to do it all in one query:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN activated = 0 THEN 'unactivated'
WHEN active = 1 AND expiry_date > CURDATE() THEN 'active'
WHEN active = 1 AND expiry_date < CURDATE() THEN 'expired'
END AS status,
yt.* FROM your_table yt;
```

You can also limit each status and do it in one query, but this would be not trivial (you'd have to use variables) and it would result in a full table scan anyway. So you don't gain anything. Therefore I'd recommend to do it in three queries. Also the above query will do a full table scan. I just posted it to give you an idea...

Comment: Is there no way to make that into one query? Or maybe I'm hoping for too much. Don't worry about the ORDER BY, it's there...

Comment: The limit is required. It's like showing a subset of results per category in a blog but now in my case I'm comparing dates.

Comment: I have also ended up creating a card_status column, made things easier which included displaying the total per status with a link to 'view all'.